# Mysql Select Second Row from 1 query

Tags: php, mysql

How do you do so we can get to the line 2 of the query in fetch?

```
Query : select * from news where id_category_news = '1'
```

I use a while for query

```
while($event_res = mysqli_fetch_array($event_query))
```

I want

Row 1 will take to :

```
                        echo '<article class="post">
                            <a class="image_thumb_zoom" href="#" title="'.$event_res['title_news'].'">
                            <img width="371" height="177" src="dist/images/dummy/shutterstock_58382248-371x177.jpg" class="attachment-post-first wp-post-image" alt="shutterstock_58382248">
                            </a>
                            <h4 class="post-title">
                            <a href="#" title="'.$event_res['title_news'].'">'.$event_res['title_news'].'</a>
                            <span class="date">'.TimetoDate($event_res['time_news']).'</span>
                            </h4>
                            <p>'.$event_res['text_news'].'</p>
                        </article>
                        ';
```

and row 2 :

```
                            <article class="post">
                                <div class="entry clearfix">
                                    <a href="#" title="Permalink to Nam nibh arcu tristique eget pretium vitae libero ac risus" rel="bookmark">
                                    <img width="225" height="136" src="dist/images/dummy/photodune-3517559-idea-s-225x136.jpg" class="thumb wp-post-image" alt="photodune-3517559-idea-s">
                                    <h4 class="post-title">Nam nibh arcu tristique eget pretiu...</h4>
                                    </a>
                                    <p>Nam nibh arcu, tristique eget pretium se...</p>
                                    <div class="meta">
                                        <span class="date">July 2, 2013</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you have an integer that increases as it goes through the rows like so:

```
$row = 1;

while($event_res = mysql_fetch_assoc($event_query)) {
   //do something here...

   if ($row == 1) {
      // do row 1 things here...

   } else if ($row == 2) {
      // do row 2 things here...
   }

   $row++;
}
```

Comment: I think you figured it out but I mean if you did it like that, another way you could do it actually because you have the unqiue column id is do `$event_res['id'] == 1` instead of `$row == 1`